# ¿Cómo llenar una selección de otra selección de diferentes tablas en la base de datos en php, Js y Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Estoy haciendo un pequeño formulario donde pide ingresar "Contraseña". Al ingresarla y presionar la tecla *Enter*, automáticamente con Ajax hace la consulta a la base de datos, y si existe esa contraseña, llena los campos de **Usuario** y **Empresa**.

El campo **Usuario** es un campo de texto, y el campo **Empresa** es un `<select>`.

Ahora bien, el problema que tengo es que también hay otro `<select>`, donde va la sucursal de la empresa seleccionada. Hasta ahora puedo llenar perfectamente el usuario y el desplegable de opciones del *select* de **Empresa**, pero lo que no he podido lograr es llenar el *select* de **Sucursal** de la BD dependiendo de la Empresa que elija el usuario.

O sea, yo deseo que al seleccionar una determinada empresa, automáticamente se llene la lista de opciones de **Sucursales** dependiendo de las sucursales que tenga la empresa que se seleccionó.

Las empresas están en una tabla diferente en la BD, y las sucursales también están en una tabla diferente. Entonces quiero hacer una consulta al *select* de **Sucursal**, verifique el ID de la empresa y muestre las sucursales indicadas para dicha empresa.

Adjunto mi código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="./app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inicio5.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Gestión 2022</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#empresa").change(function () {

                    $("#empresa option:selected").each(function () {
                        $IDEMPRESA = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/ingresar.php", { IDEMPRESA: IDEMPRESA }, function(data){
                            $("#sucursal").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });
            </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="divarriba">

       <h5>SDIG</h5>
       <h6>Gestión</h6>

       <div class="icon2 icon-key"></div>

       <h1>Gestión Web</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="esquina" style="display:none;"></div>

    <table class="ingresardatos">
        <tr>
<form method="POST">
    <td><h2 class="contraseña">Contraseña:</h2></td> <td class="td"><input class="boxcontraseña" id="contraseña" type="text" name="contraseña" autocomplete="off" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><h2 class="usuario">Usuario:</h2></td> <td><input type="text" class="boxusuario" id="usuario" name="usuario" disabled style="background:transparent; border:none;" value=""></td>
    </tr>

            <td><h2 class="empresa">Empresa:</h2></td>
            <td><select name="empresa" id="empresa" value="" style="width:98%; height:calc(1.2em + 1.2vw); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
            


            <option value="0"></option>

          
               </select></td>

       </tr>


       <td><h2 class="sucursal">Sucursal:</h2></td>
            <td><select name="sucursal" id="sucursal" value="" style="width:98%; 
            height:calc(1.2em + 1.2vw); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
            


            <option value="0"></option>

          
               </select></td>

        
    </table>

<div id="Oculto"></div>
<script>
$("input[name='contraseña']").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $.post('ingresar.php', {
            contraseña : $("input[name='contraseña']").val()
        }, function(data){
            $('#Oculto').html(data);
        });
    }
});
</script>

<div class="divabajo">

<table class="botonesabajo">
<tr>
<td><label style="color:green; background: white; font-size: calc(1em + 1vw); border-radius: 45%; width: 20%;"><input type="submit" id="register" disabled class="btingresar" value="Ingresar" name="register"></td>
<td><button class="btcancelar"><label style="color:white; font-size: calc(1em + 1vw);"></label> Cancelar</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
<?php
    include ("ingresar.php");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

y mi código php:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

$conex = mysqli_connect("SERVIDOR", "USUARIO", "CONTRASEÑA", "BD");
if ($conex->connect_error) {
    die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '. $conex->connect_error .'</p>');
  } else {
    echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successfully established.</p>';
  }
?>
<script>
    $("input[name='usuario']").val('');
    $IDEMPRESA = $_POST['IDEMPRESA'];
</script>
<?php
$contraseña = utf8_decode(is_numeric(htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_POST['contraseña']))))?$_POST['contraseña']:NULL;
if(!is_null($contraseña)){
    $consulta = 'SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE contraseña= '.$contraseña.';';
    $fila = $conex->query($consulta);
    $registro = $fila->fetch_assoc();
    $totalfilas = $conex->affected_rows;
    if($totalfilas == 0){
        echo "<script>alert('No hay valores que coincidan con la búsqueda.');</script>";
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>
            $("input[name='usuario']").val("<?php echo $registro['usuario'];?>");    



<?php
        $sql = "SELECT IDEMPRESA, NOMBRE FROM datosempresa LIMIT 10";
        $resultset = mysqli_query($conex, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conex));
        while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) { 
        ?>
        $('#empresa').append( $('<option>', { value: "<?php echo $rows["IDEMPRESA"]; ?>", text: "<?php echo $rows["NOMBRE"]; ?>"  } ) );
        <?php } 

        ?>


<?php
 $IDEMPRESA = $_POST['IDEMPRESA'];
        $sql = "SELECT  IDSUCURSAL, NOMBRE FROM sucursales WHERE IDEMPRESA = '$IDEMPRESA';";
        $resultset = mysqli_query($conex, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conex));
        while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) { 
        ?>
        $('#sucursal').append( $('<option>', { value: "<?php echo $rows["IDSUCURSAL"]; ?>", text: "<?php echo $rows["NOMBRE"]; ?>"  } ) );
        <?php } 

        ?>
    
           
        </script>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Estás metiendo un valor no numérico');</script>";
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Empieza arreglando los fallos de HTML básicos que tienes. Puedes verlos en rojo en [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/7zo2cd50/).  Luego editas la pregunta, los pones de nuevo y la miramos de nuevo.  Por otra parte, veo que todas tus preguntas van siempre de lo mismo, y llevas demasiado tiempo así. Y por último, en todas tus preguntas pones todo en un mismo párrafo que deja sin aliento a quien lo lea (eso si no entra antes en un paro cardiaco o entra en estado de shock y muere), y eso puede causar que muchos dejen de prestar atención a tu problema y pierdas posibles buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por otra parte, si te fijas, pones esto para definir una variable: `$IDEMPRESA = $(this).val();` que no pasa nada, se puede hacer sin problema aunque creo que usar el $ es más de PHP que de javascript... pero el problema es que luego la quieres usar poniendo esto: `IDEMPRESA: IDEMPRESA` lo cual **nunca** va a resolverse bien.  O pones el `$` en ambos casos o lo quitas, pero la variable deber ser identica en los dos casos, tanto cuando la defines como cuando la quieres usar.